# How to plot sectors in 3D with LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I wish to have **two sectors** (one in blue color, the other in black pencil) **in 3D**, and they share the same vertex on the plane. The black pencil one lies on the plane, whereas the blue one is theta above the plane.

The effect I am expecting is shown as the picture here.

[image]

It would be nice if I can also mark the three angles out.

I really have no clues where to start. I have also tried searching but unfortunately failed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

`MWE` with `Asymptote`:

```
% s3d.tex:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{asy}
settings.prc=false;
settings.tex="pdflatex";
settings.render=0;
import solids;
size(300);

currentprojection=orthographic(camera=(18,-90,30),up=Z,target=O,zoom=1);

real R=10;
triple A,B,C,D;

A=R*dir(70, 0); B=R*dir(60, 30);
C=(B.x,B.y,0);  D=(A.x,A.y,0);

triple p,q,r,s;

p=(-0.25R,R,0); q=(1.25R,R,0);
r=(1.25R,-R,0); s=(-0.25R,-R,0);

draw(surface(p--q--r--s--cycle),lightgreen+opacity(0.2));

real penw=0.5bp;
pen lpen=olive+penw;
pen dpen=lightblue+dashed+penw;
pen arcpen=orange+penw;

draw(A--O--B,lpen);
draw(C--O--D,dpen);
draw(B--C--D--A,dpen);

draw(arc(O,A,B,cross(A,B),CCW),arcpen);

// mark angles
real ra,rb,rth;
pen alphaPen=red;
pen betaPen=darkgreen;
pen thetaPen=blue;

ra=0.2; rb=2ra; rth=1.8ra;
draw(arc(O,ra*A,ra*B,cross(A,B),CCW),alphaPen);
draw(arc(O,rb*D,rb*C,cross(D,C),CCW),betaPen);
draw(arc(O,rth*C,rth*B,cross(C,B),CCW),thetaPen);

triple v;
v=0.5ra*(A+B);  label("$\alpha$",v,NE);
v=0.5rb*(D+C);  label("$\beta$",v,2E);
v=0.5rth*(B+C); label("$\theta$",v,NE);

dot(new triple[]{O,A,B,C,D});

defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));

label("$O$",O,W);
label("$A$",A,NE);
label("$B$",B,NE);
label("$C$",C,NE);
label("$D$",D,NE);
\end{asy}
\caption{Sectors in \texttt{3D} with \LaTeX}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
% 
% To process it with `latexmk`, create file `latexmkrc`:
% 
%     sub asy {return system("asy '$_[0]'");}
%     add_cus_dep("asy","eps",0,"asy");
%     add_cus_dep("asy","pdf",0,"asy");
%     add_cus_dep("asy","tex",0,"asy");
% 
% and run `latexmk -pdf s3d.tex`.
```

Comment: Oh my, thank you so so much!! However, I think there should be a small modification on CD. Shouldn't it be an arc instead of a straight line? Thanks! :)

Comment: I am trying to connect CD with arc just as how AB are connected. I used `draw(arc(O,D,C,cross(D,C),CCW),arcpen);`. But the arc starts from D and does NOT reach C. How may I fix it? Thanks!! :)

Comment: @perfectionm1ng: In this case `arc(O,D,C,cross(D,C),CCW)`
draws a circular arc from center `O` with radius `OD` 
in `CCW` direction to the point where it intersects the (extended) line `OC`. Since `B` is higher on the sphere than `A`, hence `OC<OD`. If you need `OC=OD` than you can place `A` and `B` at the same height, e.g. `A=R*dir(70, 0); B=R*dir(70, 30);`.

Comment: Works like a charm! Oh I see. Originally, I thought cross(D,C) meant connecting D to C... I really appreciate your time and kindness for drawing this thing out for me! I use this figure to show that $\beta$ is bigger than $\alpha$ and they can be related by $\theta$. I guess it is already the best we can do for this demonstration. :)

Comment: @perfectionm1ng: Here `cross(D,C)` returns the cross product of vectors `OD` and `OC`,
it's short for `cross(D-O,C-O)`, since here `O=(0,0,0)`, used to define a `normal` vector to the plane of the triangle `ODC`,
to draw the circular arc.
And as you'd like to demonstrate `alpha(theta)` it would be more convenient
to start with `R` and `beta`, draw the sector `OCD`, and derive `A` and `B` 
as shifted up `D` and `C`. Varying `theta` you can also build an animation.
Btw, the `alpha` can be found, e.g., from the three known sides (straight),
`arclength(O--A)`,`arclength(O--B)`,`arclength(A--B)`.